# How do you make this curl request in node

Tags: node.js, curl, https, request

This curl request to the spotify API works perfectly fine

`curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic <my-key-here>" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`

I'm trying to do this in node, but it's not working and returns a 400 Bad Request. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
function AuthRequest(key) {

  const req_body_params = JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: "client_credentials"
  })

  const base64_enc = new Buffer(key).toString("base64")

  const options = {
    host: "accounts.spotify.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "api/token",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Basic ${base64_enc}`
    }
  }

  const req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (data) {
      alert("success: " + data)
    })
  })

  req.on('error', function (err) {
    alert("error: " + err)
  })

  req.write(req_body_params)
  req.end()

}
```

I'm trying to use the Client Credentials method as explained here: `https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: 400 Bad Request

Comment: You are missing required params like the code and the redirect_uri

Comment: Your req body params should be part of your options object and they should be specified in query parameters syntax. Add `body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'` to your options object and retry the request and comment out `req.write` line

Comment: Didn't help. Same response. Also tried `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like @AngYC suggested. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should be in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON, it should be `const req_body_params = "grant_type=client_credentials"` with a header of `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

```
function AuthRequest(key) {
    const req_body_params = "grant_type=client_credentials";
    const base64_enc = new Buffer(key).toString("base64");

    const options = {
        host: "accounts.spotify.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/token",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": `Basic ${base64_enc}`
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            alert("success: " + data)
        })
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        alert("error: " + err)
    });

    req.write(req_body_params);
    req.end();
}
```

Comment: I really want this to be the answer, but I also get 400 Bad Request with this code.

Comment: I think you missed a leading slash for path?

Comment: OH NICE! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Because token expires is good to request them dynamically, I created a method that output a token as a promise, then you can consume in your request.

```
const axios = require('axios')

const client_id = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET;

function getToken( ) {
    return axios({
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        method: 'post',
        params: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        auth: {
            username: client_id,
            password: client_secret
        }
   })
}


async function getSpotifyData( endpoint ){
    const tokenData = await getToken( );
    const token = tokenData.data.access_token;
    axios({
        url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/${endpoint}`,
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).then( response =>  {
        console.log( response.data );
        return response.data;
    }).catch( error =>  {
        throw new Error(error);
    });
}
getSpotifyData( 'browse/new-releases' );
```